# MySQL using Group By to limit results

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, so I am trying to perform a query that has 4 tables,
users, events, event_roles, user_event_role.

The users can fill multiple roles. What i am trying to do is get a result that looks more like this:
User, event, Role(s)

So if user 'Bill' is associated with event 'Meeting' and 'Bill' Fills multiple roles instead of getting a result like this:

```
user   event     role
--------------------------
bill   Meeting   admin
bill   Meeting   director
```

how would I get my result to be like this

```
user   event     role    role
----------------------------------
bill   Meeting   admin   director
```

Here is a query that I'm trying to build off of.

```
Select * 
  FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN `event_role` er ON u.user_id = er.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `events` e ON er.event_id = e.event_id
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you seek is not possible.

However there is something close:

```
SELECT
  user,
  event,
  group_concat(role SEPARATOR ',') as roles
FROM
  `users` u 
  LEFT JOIN `event_role` er
    ON u.user_id = er.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN `events` e
    ON er.event_id = e.event_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

which would yield:

```
user   event     roles
----------------------
bill   Meeting   admin,director
```

In either case you would need to adjust your logic to parse it correctly.

Comment: Yep thanks, was just playing with the group_conact function and though wasn't getting the result I wanted was on the right track, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get such result, because you don't know how many roles there might be (i.e. columns count), but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` that way:

```
SELECT *,
GROUP_CONCAT(event_roles.role SEPARATOR ',') as roles
FROM users
LEFT JOIN event_role USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN events USING(user_id)
GROUP BY user_id
```

Using this query you will get all roles concatonated with `,`. But be aware of limitation of `GROUP_CONCAT`, the default value is set to 1024 characters which might not be enough (see `my.cnf`).

Comment: Good tip on the char limit, I'm just getting the role_ids, and the group by was very necessary as without that it puts the roles for every user into one result.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group_concat (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) like this. 
To show that quickly, I'm using a database from the excellent MySQL intro book by Ben Forta (http://www.forta.com/books/0672327120/), no affiliation.

```
SELECT v.vend_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.prod_id)
FROM products p 
JOIN  vendors v ON v.vend_id= p.vend_id
JOIN  orderitems oi ON oi.prod_id = p.prod_id
GROUP BY v.vend_id;
```